# how get string empty value from html decode asp.net gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, htmldecode

I have a gridview on my asp.net website. In this case, I wanna get value from the gridview row when selected. 
Here is my code behind when **gvMyTask_RowCommand**. I tried using if else condition to set specific value to my label.

```
string baselineStart = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gvrow.Cells[7].Text).ToString();

if (baselineStart == "")
    lblGLobalPlanStart.Text = "NoData"; //this condition never execute
else
    lblGLobalPlanStart.Text = baselineStart;
```

when my gridview column has data it worked for

```
lblGLobalPlanStart.Text = baselineStart; //store value
```

but when gridview column no data,this condition never execute

```
lblGLobalPlanStart.Text = "NoData";
```

is there any suggestion for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it not hit the statement, or does the statement not execute/work?
Have you tried `string.IsNullOrEmpty` or `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` ?

Comment: i tried `string.IsNullOrEmpty` for many times and doesn't work.. finally it worked when use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`. i am glad :D